# Can't update value of Office Fabric UI TextField in Enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, office-ui-fabric

I have a React component that uses `TextField` from [office-ui-fabric-react](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react)
. I'm using Enzyme/Jest to write unit tests. I'm having trouble updating the value of the `TextField`.

I've tried used `.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Input Value'} }`.

Here is my simplified version of my component:

```js
const FeedbackForm = (props: IFeedbackFormProps): JSX.Element => {
  const [comments, setComments] = React.useState<string>('');

  const onCommentChange = (_event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newValue: string): void => {
    setComments(newValue);
  };

  return (
          <TextField
            value={comments}
            onChange={onCommentChange}
          />
  );
};
```

This is my test:

```js
it('should enable the submit button when the user enters a comment', () => {
     const wrapper = shallow(<FeedbackForm {...mockProps} />);
     const commentBox = wrapper.find(TextField);
     const submitButton = wrapper.find('[type="submit"]');

     commentBox.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test value' } });

     // This button gets enabled when the text area is not empty
     expect(submitButton.is('[disabled]')).toBe(false);
   });
```

The UI works as expected. Looking at `commentBox.debug()`, the component's `value` doesn't change.

I've also verified that `onCommentChange` gets called when calling `commentBox.simulate(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about to try following ?

```
commentBox.simulate('change', { target: { id: 'id' } }, 'test value');
```